# Is there an accepted meaning for "up" and "down" an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am reading a textbook, and have been confused for a minute, until I realized that the author is using "up" and "down" an array in exactly the opposite of the way I would use it.

In particular, if we had an array with values [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], which are of course indexed as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, then I would consider the front and top of the array to be index 0 and value 1, while the back or bottom of the array is index 4 and value 5.

And thus, I'd say if we were to move the value 2 to index 0, then that would be moving *up* the array (toward the front or toward the top).  But the author of the Barron's AP CS book seems to use the opposite terminology.  Though he doesn't actually say so, his statements make sense once I assume that "up" means toward what I'd call the back or bottom of the array.  Perhaps his argument would be that this is the direction in which the index values are going up?

I suppose it would be more clear to just say "left or right" on the array, but I'm wondering if there is an accepted meaning of "up or down" and if so what is it?

Edited to clarify it is the Barron's AP CS Book, not a product of the AP itself.

Comment: My guess? Up = left

Comment: As you commented, the index values go "up" as they increase, and "down" as they decrease. However if you "print" array elements one per line from index 0 to n-1, then the start of the array will be at the "top" of the display / printout. Using left right avoids the conflict between index value ordering and a horizontal (left to right) display or printout of an array in index order.

Comment: I think it is logical for "up" to mean "higher index", i.e. towards end of array. But there is no industry norm for this, other than avoiding the use of nebulous terms like this.

Comment: Do I have three downvotes on this question?  I would appreciate some rationale.  In particular, I spent over 90 minutes researching whether an answer exists elsewhere (lack of research is criteria one for downvoting); I believe it is clear enough what is being asked (criteria two for downvoting); I believe clarity of terms is useful (criteria three for downvoting).  Please help me out here.

Comment: I believe they are down-votes, because answers to the question would be primarily opinion-based, and the question is thus *not useful*.

Comment: Your author is apparently using "up" in the sense of "toward the higher-numbered indices".  But consider that for different applications of arrays, different definitions of "up" and "down" might be appropriate.  In the case of a stack, for instance, you have the choice of fixing the head at element #0 and letting the base move toward higher indices as the stack grows, or fixing the base at element #0 and having the head move.  In either case, you'd probably defined "up" as being "toward the head", whether that turned out to mean "toward lower indices" or "toward higher indices".

Comment: @Andreas - From the OP's perspective at the time the question was posted, it could have been possible that there is an accepted meaning that the OP was unaware of. Even if if the OP had found conflicts between the usage of the terms up and down, it wouldn't necessarily mean that there wasn't an accepted usage that some violate.

Comment: The answer would be very short: "No, there is no commonly accepted meaning for "up" and "down" in an array". You would either need an explanation from the author what they meant, or figure it out from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Erwin Bolwidt states in a comment:

> No, there is no commonly accepted meaning for "up" and "down" in an array. You would either need an explanation from the author what they meant, or figure it out from the context.

On the other hand, "left" and "right" do have a commonly accepted meaning for a 1-D array.  The leftmost element is the one with the smallest index and the rightmost is the one with the largest index.

Comment: P.S. Stating ... in effect ... that there is no agreed meaning for "up" and "down" is not an opinion-based answer.  It is a statement of fact ... albeit that it is difficult to prove or provide evidence for a negative statement like this.  (But it is >>disprovable<< ... by providing evidence for an agreed meaning.)